# How can I limit the number of line breaks with React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to limit the number of line breaks a user can have in a multiline TextInput. I am looking for similar functionality as the maxLength prop, but just for breaks instead. The following code limits the breaks, but there is a delay (so it adds the line then the cursor backtracks a split second after).

```
<TextInput
  multiline={true}
  maxLength={100}
  onChangeText={(text) => this.handleChange(text)}
  value={this.state.text}
/>
```

Here is the handleChange method:

```
  handleTextChange = (text) => {
    const breaks = text.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length
    if (breaks > 4) {
      return
    } else {
      this.setState({ text: text })
    }
  }
```

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: Seems like you'll need to intercept the keydown event rather than change. `<TextInput
    onKeyPress={handleKeyDown}
   ...` and check if it would result in the case you're trying to avoid.

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't prevent the initial move of the cursor for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `numberOfLines` prop to your textInput

```js
<TextInput
  multiline={true}
  maxLength={100}
  onChangeText={this.handleChange}
  value={this.state.text}
  numberOfLines={4}
/>
```

Comment: The numberOfLines prop is only good on Android. Also, though limiting total lines could perhaps work for my case, I'm curious about limiting the amount of user breaks (aka pressing 'Enter'). So if they type 3 lines of text that wouldn't count against their break limit.